# Watching not child actor for failure due to exception

Tags: scala, akka, actor, watch

**I have the following code sample:**

```
class WatchingActor(actorToWatch: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  context watch actorToWatch

  override def receive = {
    case _: Terminated =>
      println("watched actor is dead")
  }

}

class ActorToWatch extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("")
  }
}

object Application extends App {
  implicit val ac = ActorSystem("test-sys")

  val toWatch = ac.actorOf(Props[ActorToWatch])
  val watcher = ac.actorOf(Props(new WatchingActor(toWatch)))

  toWatch ! "lol"

}
```

Is it possible somehow to supervise ActorToWatch failure(is exception was thrown) without making it child of WatchingActor ?
In this sample "watched actor is dead" is not printed, I guess because ActorToWatch is restarted on excpetion, instead of stopping. How to handle the failure of watched actor that is not child ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `ActorToWatch` gets restarted after failing. And this is because the default supervision strategy for the Guardian Actor is to restart it. You can change the Guardian's strategy to - e.g. - a stopping one, by applying the following configuration in your `application.conf`.

```
actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy = "akka.actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy"
```

You can devise more complex strategies, but this one should get your deathwatch triggered.

For more info on supervision see the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/supervision.html).

Comment: Is it possible to change supervision strategy for one specific actor, which is not child of WatchingActor ?

Comment: You can change any actor's supervision strategy (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fault-tolerance.html#Creating_a_Supervisor_Strategy). If you want to apply different behaviour depending on the child, then you might want to throw different exceptions in your children to distinguish them.

Comment: Could you illustrate it in your answer to be clear. I read the documentation and there is written, I try it. It works if I make WatchingActor parent of ActorToWatch.

Comment: Question is it possible to do the same without parent - child relationship between actors

Comment: I think there might be 2 things discussed at the same time. 1. the supervision is by definition a parent-child relationship. 2. a deathwatch can be setup between any pair of actors, not necessarily a parent and its child